PDE's that give rise to martingales in relation to Brownian motion
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
It is well known that if $\on{f}\left(x,t\right)$ is a $C^{2}$ function satisfying
$\on{f}_{t} + \on{f}_{xx}/2 = 0$ then $\on{f}\left(B_{t},t\right)$ is a Martingale.

This is an immediate consequence of the $2$-d Ito Formula.
This fact gives rise to the Hermite Martingales and Exponential Martingale of Brownian Motion.
My question is, I remember once, along time ago, seeing an extension of this, but I can't find it now:

It was another PDE which, if satisfied by $\on{f}\left(x,y,t\right)$, would yield a Martingale when we considered $\on{f}\left(B_{t},S_{t},t\right)$, where I believe $S_{t}$ was the Supremum Process of Brownian Motion, but it may have been
$\left\vert B_{t}\right\vert$, my memory is a bit hazy here.



Has anyone seen this before, or other results of this type ?. Thanks, Greg.

Isn't it true for any semimartingale $X_t$ that by applying Ito's formula, you immediately get a PDE such that $f(X_t)$ is a martingale when $f$ satisfies the PDE?

I'm not sure. I do believe that if $X_t$ is a diffusion, and $f$ satisfies $Lf + f_t = 0$, where $L$ is the generator of $X$, then $f(X_t,t)$ is a martingale. Is that what you mean?

Set $Z_t = f(B_t,S_t,t)$. By Ito's formula
$$dZ_t = \partial_x f(B_t,S_t,t)dB_t + \partial_y f(B_t,S_t,t)dS_t + \Big(\frac{1}{2}\partial^2_x f(B_t,S_t,t) + \partial_t f(B_t,S_t,t)\Big)dt.$$
Then $Z$ is a local martingale whenever $\frac{1}{2}\partial^2_x f + \partial_t f = 0$ on $\{(x,y,t) : x \le y\}$ and $\partial_y f = 0$ on $\{(x,y,t) : x = y\}$. The last condition is because the Stieltjs measure $dS_t$ is carried by $\{t : B_t = S_t\}$.

Thanks, I see what you mean. That may be what I saw but I'm not sure. Do you know of any paper that contains this fact?

No, I do not. Sorry.
